# Amazon FireTV without WiFi, MacBook Pro Internet sharing

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, television

I've been struggling for a while on this, strange set of circumstances. 
I have a Amazon FireTV box that I cannot connect as university wireless does not support it.

I'm looking for a way to set up Internet from my MacBook pro (the uni WiFi won't allow Internet sharing however - and no Ethernet in my room!). 
The only way i've found is to share my iPhone's 4G but I don't want to do that because of data usage.

Any way I can fix this?

I have an iPhone, iPad, Macbook Pro, HDMI cables, USB cables but not WiFi that I'm allowed to share!

Anything I can buy to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**  **Not without getting you in hot water with your school/university.**

Technically speaking, you *could* have a setup that consisted of:

- a WiFi router with a network specifically for your dorm room
- Ethernet from router to MacBook
- MacBook connected to Uni WiFi
- Internet sharing routed from Ethernet on MacBook to MacBook WiFi

Would that work?  Yes, your Amazon FireTV would connect to *your* dorm room WiFi that you create and traffic would be routed through Ethernet, through your Mac, to the Uni WiFi and out to the University's network.

Should you do this?

Absolutley not.

- They can detect your WiFi network
- The "enterprise grade" networking gear can detect that you are sharing the network connection
- The traffic shaper firewall/appliance they are probably using will detect your (prohibited) network traffic

The key here to remember is:

```
Their network = their rules.
```

You can/will be discovered and your university "career" (IMO) isn't worth the risk.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! Not only have you provided a means for the OP to achieve their goal,  but you've also explained the risks and why they shouldn't. Obviously it's their choice in the end, but at least you've made it clear that their university will detect what they're doing.